# how to wire up a 12V solenoid valve without alligator clips

Tags: wiring

I have got a very beginner question.
I am building an irrigation system and so I need to use a 12V solenoid valve.
My question is as follows:
Given the following valve and in particular the contacts (at the bottom):
[image]
I have connected it to my relay (and ground) with some alligator clip to **prototype** (it works), but how can I connect it in a more serious (*production*-ready) way?

Thanks,

Comment: just a note: the picture shows the valve upside down .... always orient with electrics at the highest point, to keep water out as much as possible

Comment: yes. I found the picture on the internet, but your comment makes a LOT of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectors you see in the image are known as [spade connectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FCFH84Q), also push-on spade connectors, typically in insulated and non-insulated forms.

The above Amazon link is but one of many sources. [Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/search?q=spade%20connectors) has available for purchase a few assortments of terminal connectors. For small quantities, at proportional higher prices, one can certainly find these spade connectors at local auto parts stores. I have three stores within two miles and all of them carry various sizes of the connector, both male and female connections.

[image: insulated pair spade connectors]

Above image of insulated male/female spade connectors courtesy of Lowes™

You'll probably find that you can only buy matched sets, if you need only the two. Maybe a box of six, three of each, at an auto parts store. Check the wire gauge you plan to use and match that with the legend on the box.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, so I need to buy 2 female spade connectors, right?

Comment: That would be correct. More in the original answer.